HCL Notes - Using @ThisName as a variable
I am moving a lot of upper case text from PDFs to fields in Notes. There are numerous fields receiving the text. I want to change the case of the text using @ProperCase.
Since there are receiving fields through out a rather large form, I need to perform the case conversion using an action button in the toolbar of the form.
To specify where I want the converted text I am trying to use @ThisName as a variable in (what will be) a hidden field. Here is an example of what I've tried.
Start := @ThisName;
@Command([EditGotoField];"Holding");
@SetField("Holding";"");
@Command([EditPaste]);
@Command([EditGotoField];"Holding");
@SetField("Holding";@ProperCase(Holding));
@Command([EditGotoField];"Holding");
@Command([EditSelectAll]);
@Command([EditCopy]);
@Command([EditGotoField];"Start");
@Command([EditPaste])

"Start" is a variable for the field where I want to converted text to appear.
"Holding" is an actual field I use to perform the conversion.
The trouble starts at line 10, where I am trying to get the converted text into the field where I want it.
Any assistance will be most appreciated.

@SetField(@ThisName; @ProperCase(@ThisValue))

You try to go to the field "Start", but you want to go to the field that is defined in the variable Start. Just change this line like this:
@Command([EditGotoField];Start);
Then it will work

Note working yet. I failed to mention that the Holding field is an OS Style field. The reason being that when I copy and paste the pdf text into the form, it comes with what appear to be carriage returns but I'm not sure they are. Whatever they are, pasting them into Holding strips them away. Here is my most recent attempt.
Start := @ThisName;
@Command([EditGotoField];"Holding");
@SetField("Holding";"");
@Command([EditPaste]);
@Command([EditGotoField];"Holding");
@SetField("Holding";@ProperCase(Holding));
@Command([EditGotoField];Start);
@GetField("Holding")
